# Permissions list changes in ice cream sandwitch

Tags: android, security, permissions

I know [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) is the list of permissions in android

Is there any new permissions added in android 4.0 ?

Is there some new permission in the list that does not existed in 2.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for new premissions in 4.0 http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html

see this for changes in any version is under `Downloadable SDK Components`
 http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1-highlights.html